# Display alert based on value and session

Tags: php, session

What I am trying to accomplish is if the user verified column is 0 it will echo out the message below if the users verified column is 1 it wont show the message.

so I have it working but if they close it I don't want it to show again for that session.

```
$db = dbconnect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['ID']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $verified = $row['Verified'];

      if ($verified == 0) {            

       echo '
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          Your account has not been verified.
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>';

            return true;        

        } else {

         return false;            
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a session variable to show the alert based off of the value retrieved from the database, like so :

**PHP**

---

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['verifymsg']) {
        $_SESSION['VerifyMessage'] = false;
    }
}

$db = dbconnect();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['ID']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['ID'];

    if (!isset($_SESSION['VerifyMessage']) {
        $_SESSION['VerifyMessage'] = ($row['Verified'] == 0) ? true : false;
     }

  if ($_SESSION['VerifyMessage']) {            

   echo '
<form method="POST" action="yourscript.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="verifymsg" />
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      Your account has not been verified.
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
</form>';

        return true;        

    } else {

     return false;            
  }
}
```

Here, I used a [ternary operation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to set a session variable called 'VerifyMessage' if it isn't already set. I also added a `<form>` and hidden input with the name `verifymsg` to the html.

When this script sees `verifymsg` as a post variable, it will set the session variable to `false`. This can work anyway you want, for example with ajax, but it shows a concept.